# How to code an alert message to prompt after directing to URL header location (PHP)

Tags: php

The alert echo does not appear after the redirection in my else statement, may i request some assistance in getting this to work the way i want?

```
    if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
        header("Location:http://localhost/swapproject/index.php");
        
        debug();
    }
    else {
        header("Location:http://localhost/swapproject/loginform.php");
        echo '<script>alert("please enter valid login info")</script>';
        debug();
        die();
    }
```

I tried the echo 'alert("please enter valid login info")'; before and after the header in the else statement. I want the alert prompt to display after it redirects the fella back to the loginform screen as he entered his details incorrectly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you return a response that tells the browser to redirect the user:

```
header("Location:http://localhost/swapproject/loginform.php");
```

Then there's no reason to return any page content.  While some browsers may behave differently, by and large they're just going to ignore the content.  Because there's no reason to display it when one is just *immediately* redirecting the user to another page.

Instead, put the `alert` on your `loginform.php` page.  If that page needs to only conditionally show that `alert`, you can wrap it in a condition:

```
if (isset($_GET['alert'])) {
  echo '<script>alert("please enter valid login info")</script>';
}
```

And pass a query string parameter on the redirect to trigger it:

```
header("Location:http://localhost/swapproject/loginform.php?alert=true");
```